# How to formally write the set of all elements that are entries of a given vector?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let $Q$ be an arbitrary set with generic element $q_i\in Q$ and let $\mathbf{q}\equiv(q_1,q_2,\dots)$ be a vector. I want to construct the set of all elements $q_i\in Q$ that are entries of the vector $\mathbf{q}$. However, I’m having trouble formally writing this set. Any help?

Thank you all!

Comment: When you write "vector", do you mean an element of a vector space, or just a list? The entries in the representation of a vector in some given basis are elements of a field, so $Q$ cannot be arbitrary, it would need to be a subset of the field of the vector space, or the set you construct would be empty. Also, you would need to specify both the vector and the chosen basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what your index set is, I would suggest
$$\bigcup_{i}\;\{q_i\}$$
If you want to be more specific:
$$\bigcup_{1\le i\le n}\;\{q_i\}$$
or perhaps
$$\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb N}\;\{q_i\}$$

Answer (score 1):

Given $q_i$ with $1 \leq i \leq n$ let $Q=\{x \mid \exists i \text{ with }  1 \leq i \leq n \text{ such that }  x = q_i   \}$

Also we can say $Q=q(I)$ where $I$ is the index set of the vector $q_i$. I see $q_i$ like a function $q:I \rightarrow X$.

Answer (score 0):

While the other two answers do work, I think that the standard way of denoting this set would be $$\{q_i | i \in I\}$$ where $I$ is the index set for your vector.